# How can I adjust the css within fusion theme based on the size of the screen?

Tags: theming

I'm using the [Fusion theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/fusion) for its responsive components but there are some things I want to tweak on the different layouts based on the screen size of the device viewing.

How can I apply style changes to say the phone layout, but not change the desktop and tablet layouts?

As a working example, lets say I wanted to accomplish the following:

```
/* Desktop + Tablet */
h1 {
  color: red;
}

/* Phones */
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Are there selectors I should be using to accomplish this type of fine tuning?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this post on [media queries and width attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) useful.

Comment: Is this generally how Fusion themers accomplish this kind of edit?  I'm very new to responsive theming and want to follow the 'standards' as closely as possible while I'm learning. :)

Comment: I don't know about Fusion at all, but all themes use CSS and media queries are how CSS determines what sort of device you are using.